# Input and Label isnt overflowing

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to follow a video to make an animation on a input and label. I have done it once today already at school but now it happens to appear to not work.

Basically I am trying to get the label inside the "input" and the input is the full size of the div as well. Well, when I do pos absolute on the label it goes outside the "form" div somehow and IDK why.

```css
.register {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.form {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
}

.form input {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.form label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="register">
  <h1>Register</h1>
  <div class="form">
    <input type="text" name="firstN" autocomplete="off" required>
    <label for="firstN"><span>Name</span></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: How It Looks Like]

Comment: have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Change `css` code like this:

```
  .form label {
   position: absolute;
   left:15px;
   top:15px;
 }
```

when you `pos` absolute you need to set `left` or `top` too.

```css
.register {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.form {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
}
.form input {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-color:gray;
}
.form label {
    position: absolute;
  
    left:15px;
    top:25px;
   
}
```

```html
<div class="register">
  <h1>Register</h1>
  <div class="form">
    <input type="text" name="firstN" autocomplete="off" required>
    <label for="firstN"><span>Name</span></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `placeholder` attribute insted:

```
<input placeholder="Name">
```

Or write more lines in CSS:

```
label{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

```css
.register {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.form {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
}

.form input {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.form label {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="register">
  <h1>Register</h1>
  <div class="form">
    <input type="text" name="firstN" autocomplete="off" required>
    <label for="firstN"><span>Name</span></label>
  </div>
</div>
```